# How to update package reference in project C# by Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget-package, packagereference

I have a common source C# and this is inject in another project.

Now I have update this common source

But I don't know to update version in other source

[image]

How can I do this??

I want to update verion of common source that I have updated into another source

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, pasting the text directly into the question is preferred over a screenshot.

It looks like the common source is a NuGet package? Have you deployed the updated package to NuGet? If so, you should be able to use Manage NuGet Packages, Update.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Search engines can quickly take you to the guides like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#update-a-package or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#update-a-package Stack Overflow is not the right place for tutorials on how to use Visual Studio (consider that so many guides have been published by Microsoft already).

Comment: Hi @LexLi this question is not how to use Visual studio. I just don't know how to do to config this. Another, I had been research this before ask in stackoverflows but I can not find satisfactory answer. Thanks